# TensorFlow Distributed Runtime Model Parallel CIFAR-10

Tags: python, runtime, distributed, tensorflow

I have tried to modify the CIFAR-10 example to run on the new TensorFlow distributed runtime. However, I get the following error when trying to run the program:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device to node 'softmax_linear/biases/ExponentialMovingAverage': 
Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/job:local/task:0/device:CPU:0'
```

I start the cluster using the following commands. On the first node I run:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_tensorflow_server --cluster_spec='local|10.31.101.101:7777;10.31.101.224:7778' --job_name=local --task_id=0
```

...and on the second node I run:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_tensorflow_server --cluster_spec='local|10.31.101.101:7777;10.31.101.224:7778' --job_name=local --task_id=1
```

For the [CIFAR-10 multi-GPU code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py), I make the simple modifications, replacing two lines in the `train()` function. The following line:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.device('/cpu:0'):
```

...is replaced with:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.device('/job:local/task:0/cpu:0'):
```

and the following line:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
```

...is replaced with:

```
with tf.device('/job:local/task:0/gpu:%d' % i):
```

In my understanding, the second substitution should take care of the model substitution.  Running a simpler example, like the code below, works fine:

```
with tf.device('/job:local/task:0/cpu:0'):
    c = tf.constant("Hello, distributed TensorFlow!")
    sess.run(c)
    print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from your program, but my guess is that you also have to modify the [line that creates the session](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/263d00d2710779d5c4ac66e335b2ba07d8385b6b/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py#L234) to specify the address of one of your worker tasks. For example, given your configuration above, you might write:

```
sess = tf.Session(
    "grpc://10.31.101.101:7777",
    config=tf.ConfigProto(
        allow_soft_placement=True,
        log_device_placement=FLAGS.log_device_placement))
```

As it happens, we've been trying to improve that error message to make it less confusing. If you update to the latest version in GitHub and run the same code, you should see an error message that explains *why* the device specification could not be satisfied.